# Is there a better way to insert into related tables at once?

Tags: sql-server

It's been years since I had a look at how to do an insert into related tables.  I've always done it by writing stored procedures, but in the last 8 years or so I never tried to see if there was a better way.  I was wondering if there was a better way maybe a joined insert.

So say I have these 2 tables.

**[Users]**

```
UserID (Identity, Primary Key)
Name
UserExtendedPropertyID (Foreign Key, Indexed)
```

**[UserExtendedProperty]**

```
UserExtendedPropertyID (Identity, Primary Key)
Address
Phone
```

Say I wanted to insert a new user.  I would traditionally write a stored procedure that would do something like:

```
insert into UserExtendedPropertyID (Address, Phone) values('123 Fake St.', '867-5309')
set @myidentity = select @@identity
insert into Users (Name, UserExtendedPoerpertyID) values('John Doe', @myidentity)
```

Always felt like there should be one query that would let me do a joined insert, but I never found such a thing.

Comment: Unfortunately no. When the record is ready to get inserted in the table 2, based on the foreign key constraint, it should have a value corresponding to an item in table 1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it **except** if you will **not** enforce FKey constraint between these tables, then you may try to do the following, if Sql Server version is 2005+:

```
insert into UserExtendedProperty (Address, Phone) 
OUTPUT 
  'John Doe', 
  INSERTED.UserExtendedPropertyId 
INTO Users(NAME, UserExtendedPropertyId)
values('123 Fake St.', '867-5309')
```

**But why** do you want such a behavior, for atomicity - use transaction, what else?

Comment: Very nice.  But, as you've said, having to disable fk constraint negates any benefits.  Maybe on the next SQL server release, they will let us do this while fk constraints are enabled.  They can call this feature "uncommitted foreign key unconstrainted inserts".  After all, it is only the validation check that fails.  And in this case, the validation wasn't necessary because we already know it is valid.

Comment: As I said - no way with FK enabled

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oleg Dok response. In addition to that I would like to point out a possible problem with your existing script.

It is **NOT** advisable to use @@Identity or SCOPE_IDENTITY() without including

```
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Please check this http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811

Extract from the above link:

> **Posted by Microsoft on 3/18/2008 at 1:10 PM**
>
> Dave, thanks to your very detailed and dilligent report I was able to
>   find the problem. **Yes, it's a bug - whenever a parallel query plan is
>   generated @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY() are not being updated
>   consistenly and can't be relied upon.** The few workarounds I can offer
>   you for now:
>
> 1. Use MAX_DOP=1 as you are already using. This may hurt performance of the SELECT part of your query.
> 2. Read the value from SELECT part into a set of variables (or single tabel variable) and then insert into the target table with MAX_DOP=1.
>      Since the INSERT plan will not be parallel you will get the right
>      semantic, yet your SELECT will be parallel to achieve performance
>      there if you really need it.
> 3. Use OUTPUT clause of INSERT to get the value you were looking for, as in the example I give further below. In fact I highly recomend
>      using OUTPUT instead of @@IDENTITY in all cases. It's just the best
>      way there is to read identity and timestamp.
> 4. Changing autostas is NOT a good workaround. It may hide the problem for a while but a prallel plan will get produced eventually.
> 5. Force serial plans for entire server via sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism' option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I had no idea that a bug of this magnitude was out there, and MS has yet to do anything about it. That is just insane.  Will be using OUTPUT from now on.  Much appreciated!